# Add response header in halt

Tags: spark-java

I'm running into a situation where I'd like to add some response headers, to adhere to the RFC when returning a 401 Unauthorized response, when calling the `Spark.halt` method. It supports setting the response code and body, but does not have the ability to add response headers.
I could workaround around this limitation by using [Exception Mapping](http://sparkjava.com/documentation#exception-mapping), but this results in disconnected code.

Is there possibly another better workaround? Or would it be reasonable to add support to `HaltException` to specify headers to add?